# Copy -data to other ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy

I have a ul with data attributes. Like this:

```
<ul class="carousel-creations">
    <li data-teaflavour="pear">
    </li>
    <li data-teaflavour="mint">
    </li>
    <li data-teaflavour="chai">
    </li>
    <li data-teaflavour="mint">
    </li>
    <li data-teaflavour="pear">
    </li>
    <li data-teaflavour="chai">
    </li>
</ul>
```

But my problem is. I want to copy the data atributs to other ul. This is my second ul.

```
<ul class="controlNav">
    <li><a rel="0" title="" class=""></a><span class="hover"></span></li>
    <li><a rel="1" title="" class=""></a><span class="hover"></span></li>
    <li><a rel="2" title="" class=""></a><span class="hover"></span></li>
    <li><a rel="3" title="" class="active"></a><span class="hover"></span></li>
    <li><a rel="4" title="" class=""></a><span class="hover"></span></li>
    <li><a rel="5" title="" class=""></a><span class="hover"></span></li>
</ul>
```

I want that the data attribuuts of the first ul. Are copy to the ul controlNav. Do you understand my bad english? (A) I want to copy the data attribute to the second ul. So that all items of the second ul li. The data attributes getting the first ul.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the list items with [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/), and use the supplied `index` argument to locate the appropriate item in the other list:

```
var $sourceItems = $("ul.carousel-creations li");
$("ul.controlNav li").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr("data-teaflavour",
        $sourceItems.eq(index).attr("data-teaflavour"));
});
```

Comment: @ThiefMaster, because `data()` does fetch the HTML5 data attributes on read, but does not create them on write, so I thought using `attr()` for both reads and writes was clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery's [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to copy the data attributes, use `$(target).data($(source).data());` - obviously you have to replace *source* and *target*.